# Updating rows in MediaStore, get error Unknown or unsupported URL

Tags: android, mediastore

I'm trying to update the some rows in `MediaStore.Audio.Albums` that go by id `ALBUM_ID`, but I get this error

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown or unsupported URL: content://media/internal/audio/albums

Here is the code:

```
ctx.getContentResolver().update(
    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
    values, 
    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ID + "=" + 16, 
    null);
```

Answer (score 0):

`.update()` always throws this error no matter what

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown or unsupported URL: content://media/internal/audio/albums

To update, delete the rows first, and then insert them again.

**For example**

First, delete the rows you want to update

```
Uri albumArtUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");

ctx.getContentResolver().delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(albumArtUri, 16), null, null);
ctx.getContentResolver().delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(albumArtUri, 25), null, null);
ctx.getContentResolver().delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(albumArtUri, 24), null, null);
ctx.getContentResolver().delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(albumArtUri, 30), null, null);
ctx.getContentResolver().delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(albumArtUri, 14), null, null);
ctx.getContentResolver().delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(albumArtUri, 31), null, null);
ctx.getContentResolver().delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(albumArtUri, 28), null, null);
ctx.getContentResolver().delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(albumArtUri, 23), null, null);
ctx.getContentResolver().delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(albumArtUri, 17), null, null);
ctx.getContentResolver().delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(albumArtUri, 16), null, null);
ctx.getContentResolver().delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(albumArtUri, 13), null, null);
```

Second, re-insert the rows

```
ContentValues insertionValues = new ContentValues();

insertionValues.put("_data", "Dummy path");
insertionValues.put("album_id", 16);
ctx.getContentResolver().insert(albumArtUri, insertionValues);

insertionValues.put("_data", "Dummy path");
insertionValues.put("album_id", 25);
ctx.getContentResolver().insert(albumArtUri, insertionValues);

insertionValues.put("_data", "Dummy path");
insertionValues.put("album_id", 24);
ctx.getContentResolver().insert(albumArtUri, insertionValues);

insertionValues.put("_data", "Dummy path");
insertionValues.put("album_id", 30);
ctx.getContentResolver().insert(albumArtUri, insertionValues);

insertionValues.put("_data", "Dummy path");
insertionValues.put("album_id", 14);
ctx.getContentResolver().insert(albumArtUri, insertionValues);

insertionValues.put("_data", "Dummy path");
insertionValues.put("album_id", 31);
ctx.getContentResolver().insert(albumArtUri, insertionValues);

insertionValues.put("_data", "Dummy path");
insertionValues.put("album_id", 28);
ctx.getContentResolver().insert(albumArtUri, insertionValues);

insertionValues.put("_data", "Dummy path");
insertionValues.put("album_id", 23);
ctx.getContentResolver().insert(albumArtUri, insertionValues);

insertionValues.put("_data", "Dummy path");
insertionValues.put("album_id", 17);
ctx.getContentResolver().insert(albumArtUri, insertionValues);

insertionValues.put("album_id", 16);
insertionValues.put("_data", "Dummy path");
ctx.getContentResolver().insert(albumArtUri, insertionValues);

insertionValues.put("album_id", 13);
insertionValues.put("_data", "Dummy path");
ctx.getContentResolver().insert(albumArtUri, insertionValues);
```

If you print the results

```
dumpCursorByAlbumId("16");
dumpCursorByAlbumId("25");
dumpCursorByAlbumId("24");
dumpCursorByAlbumId("30");
dumpCursorByAlbumId("14");
dumpCursorByAlbumId("31");
dumpCursorByAlbumId("28");
dumpCursorByAlbumId("23");
dumpCursorByAlbumId("17");
dumpCursorByAlbumId("16");
dumpCursorByAlbumId("13");
```

You'll see all you did was update the individual cells!

```
0 {
   _id=16
   album_art=Dummy path
   artist=Keith Jarrett & Charlie Haden
   artist=Keith Jarrett & Charlie Haden
   numsongs=9
   album_key=   ?   )   M   O       /   )   C   -   1   1611567005
}
<<<<<
>>>>> Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@26cf2dde
0 {
   _id=25
   album_art=Dummy path
   artist=John Coltrane
   artist=John Coltrane
   numsongs=4
   album_key=   ?   E   S   1       M   Q   G   K   1   A   1       S   1   K   S   1       K   1   9   M   M   Q   1   596735119
}
<<<<<
>>>>> Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@3de45bbf
0 {
   _id=24
   album_art=Dummy path
   artist=Charlie Parker
   artist=Charlie Parker
   numsongs=50
   album_key=   1   M   M   1   C   -   1       E   3       -   7   )   K   ?   9   1       G   )   K   =   1   K   1076433605
}
<<<<<
>>>>> Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@22e9728c
0 {
   _id=30
   album_art=Dummy path
   artist=Bill Evans Trio
   artist=Bill Evans Trio
   numsongs=10
   album_key=   M   Q   C   /   )   Y       )   O       O   7   1       S   9   ?   ?   )   5   1       S   )   C   5   Q   )   K   /   -379248890
}
<<<<<
>>>>> Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@22949dd5
0 {
   _id=14
   album_art=Dummy path
   artist=Lester Young, Teddy Wilson Quartet
   artist=Lester Young, Teddy Wilson Quartet
   numsongs=7
   album_key=   G   K   1   M       )   C   /       O   1   /   /   Y   1537972582
}
<<<<<
>>>>> Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@291c49ea
0 {
   _id=31
   album_art=Dummy path
   artist=Ahmad Jamal
   artist=Ahmad Jamal
   numsongs=8
   album_key=   1   M   M   1   C   -   1       E   3       )   7   A   )   /       ;   )   A   )   ?       G   O           -196083261
}
<<<<<
>>>>> Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@348cf4db
0 {
   _id=28
   album_art=Dummy path
   artist=Bill Evans Trio
   artist=Bill Evans Trio
   numsongs=10
   album_key=   1   W   G   ?   E   K   )   O   9   E   C   M   1375882484
}
<<<<<
>>>>> Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@f012b78
0 {
   _id=23
   album_art=Dummy path
   artist=Sonny Rollins
   artist=Sonny Rollins
   numsongs=5
   album_key=   M   )   W   E   G   7   E   C   1       -   E   ?   E   M   M   Q   M   248432292
}
<<<<<
>>>>> Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@158e4251
0 {
   _id=17
   album_art=Dummy path
   artist=Wayne Shorter
   artist=Wayne Shorter
   numsongs=7
   album_key=   M   G   1   )   =       C   E       1   S   9   ?   1951230391
}
<<<<<
>>>>> Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@216d1ab6
0 {
   _id=16
   album_art=Dummy path
   artist=Keith Jarrett & Charlie Haden
   artist=Keith Jarrett & Charlie Haden
   numsongs=9
   album_key=   ?   )   M   O       /   )   C   -   1   1611567005
}
<<<<<
>>>>> Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@185c03b7
0 {
   _id=13
   album_art=Dummy path
   artist=Bill Evans & Shelly Manne
   artist=Bill Evans & Shelly Manne
   numsongs=6
   album_key=   1   A   G   )   O   7   Y   1349167640
}
```

`dumpCursorByAlbumId` class

```
public void dumpCursorByAlbumId(String id){
    String[] stringArray = {id};
    final Cursor mCursor = ctx.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, // Uri
            new String[]{                                 // String[] projection (columns)
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.NUMBER_OF_SONGS,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_KEY
            },
            MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID + "=?",           // String selection
            stringArray,                                  // String[] selectionArgs
            null                                         // sortOrder
    );

    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {

        // dump each row in the cursor
        // for(int i=0; i <  stringArray.length; i++){
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(mCursor);
        // mCursor.moveToNext();
        //}

        mCursor.close();

    }
    else {
        mCursor.close();
    }
}
```